# If one or two boxes are open / closed, open / close the remainders (if all are open, close all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This one is tricky! I've spent hours and hours on this, can't find anything similar on Stackoverflow, probably because I'm not sure what to search for.

**The issue:**

1. In a container I have 3 boxes that each have an open/close toggle button — that toggles them individually — **it works fine.**
2. I have one Open-Close All button outside of the container, that should be able to open the remaining boxes `(if 1 or 2 are already open)` OR if all / or none are open, it should open / close them all.

My code almost does everything that I need `(if 1 or 2 boxes are open and you click Open-Close All, the remainder opens)` and if all boxes are closed, Open-Close opens them all at once.

**Only thing that doesn't work is if ALL boxes are open, I want to be able to close them all at once by clicking Open-Close All.**

http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/ZbrvOO

```
$('.small-box-button').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.small-box').toggleClass('is-visible');

});

// Open / Close all / remainders
$('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($('.small-box').is(':visible')) {
 // then open the small boxes that are not open yet (the remainders) 
      $('.small-box').siblings().addClass('is-visible');
   //  $(this).next('.small-box').toggleClass('is-visible');
}
  //not sure what to do here... 
 else ($('.small-box').not(':visible')) 
       $('.small-box').siblings().addClass('is-visible');
});
```

I think I need to use some more if else conditions and check for values `(like if isVisible >= 1 || 2 )` but not sure how to write it. 
I have a feeling this could be written much simpler.

Would really appreciate some guidance, I did my best to make the example as easy to look at as possible.

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Yeh that should be doable....

Comment: There is no 'Open/Close' button on your code pen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is very easy. Basically what you have to do is check the number of items are you showing when the user click de main button out site the box. Take a look below:

// Open/close all boxes 
  $('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();

```
var numOfItems = $('.is-visible').length;

if(numOfItems > 1){ //Add the case you need
  //Remove all the .is-visible
}else{
  //Add to all the boxes .is-visible 
}
```

});

Also I recommend you encapsulate your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Toggle individual boxes when clicking on buttons inside container
  $('.small-box-button').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.small-box').toggleClass('is-visible');

  });
  // Open/close all boxes 
  $('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    var numOfItems = $('.is-visible').length;

    if(numOfItems > 1){ //Add the case you need
      //Remove all the .is-visible
    }else{
      //Add to all the boxes .is-visible 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This works perfect as well, the code looks quite different than Milind Anantwar's answer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdQoVG  — may I ask why you're using var? Does it make the code run faster or?  I'm really curious about this stuff, and I think it's interesting to get two different answers that both work perfect.  Thank you! :-)

Comment: Well feel free to use the one you want. Happy to help you! :) @Capax

Comment: Sorry I hit submit by mistake before I was done writing, i just edited my above comment!

Comment: Well just set the condition => `if(numOfItems > 1)`, if you want to show all if is lees than 1 or whatever you need, but the concept is that. :) @Capax

Comment: Maybe make more sense is you also set the text in your button to show all or hide all and set a different action for each click, so you can avoid some problems. it's your shoes. @Capax

Comment: Hey gon250, I implemented your code and it works great. But then I tried to make the button text switch like you recommend. I added two span classes (.open-all & .close-all) and added it below the condition if numOfItems — so if all boxes are open, the text span should switch to Close All / if not, it should remain "Open All". Can you see what I'm doing wrong in the code? http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/zvRWdx  :-)

Comment: @Capax I'm a little bit busy at work but I have changed a little bit your code, the main idea is there http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/p8fnjmd1/1/ so just take a look it and fix whatever if you see any error, what you have todo is set the button text not hide or show the button.

Comment: appreciate it.  But I seriously can't make that Open / Close button register how many boxes are open no matter how I manipulate your code, I'm not sure what's missing but I'll keep trying :-)

Comment: @Capax hey sorry for the late, have u fixed the issue?

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help! :-) But I think maybe I phrased the issue wrong. If you go in and manually open each box with its own button (1, 2, 3)  (so all 3 boxes are open), my wish is to make the Open All button switch its label to Close All.  Right now the button text remains "Open All" — so it doesn't register that all boxes have been clicked open.

Comment: — maybe it would be easier if each individual button had an ID that could be stored in a variable (in an array?), and then when you click on the buttons you could register how many buttons have been clicked. Then if all 3 buttons have been clicked, the Close All / Open all switches text? I'm not sure, still new to this, but I'll keep trying :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggleClass()` function with classname as argument and condition that checks the length of visible element:

```
$('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(){
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.small-box').siblings().toggleClass('is-visible',$('.small-box').length != $('.small-box.is-visible').length);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdQoVG)**

Comment: or `$('.small-box').siblings().toggleClass($('.small-box').length == $('.small-box:visible').length)`

Comment: @mplungjan: was going to update that. wasn't sure about argument order :)

Answer (score 1):

Full working solution : (copy & paste & check)

Very small change needed in your own code,
the correct Javascript code would be as such

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Toggle individual boxes when clicking on buttons inside container
    $('.small-box-button').on('click', function(e){
      $(this).next('.small-box').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });

    // Open/close all boxes
    $('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(e){
        if($(".small-box.is-visible").length < $(".small-box").length){
            $(".small-box:not([class*='is-visible'])").addClass("is-visible");
        }else{
            $(".small-box").removeClass("is-visible");
        }
    });
});
```

Also i have updated your example link and it works fine , 
Have a look in the below link and test it if its all what u needed :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVLvRK

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for `:hidden` selector:

```
$('.open-close-all-button').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.small-box:hidden').addClass('is-visible');
});
```